# .Net MVC 4 Dropdownlistfor SelectedItem (Not just selected value, but the selected text)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a for loop to generate IEnumerable list:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> loadData()
{
    DataTable dt = load_from_database;
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        SelectListItem listItem = new SelectListItem();
        listItem.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
        listItem.Value = dr["id"].ToString();
        list.Add(listItem);
    }
    return list;
}
```

And I have the following model:

```
public class Models
{
    public string selectedUserApp { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> userApps  { get; set;  }
}
```

And the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new UserApplicationModels();
    userAppsList = loadData();
    model.userApps = userAppsList;
    model.selectedUserApp = model.userApps.First().Value;

    return View(model);
}
```

Then the view:

```
@model Models

@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.selectedUserApp , Model.userApps)
```

What I got is the value of the selected item, but I need to get the text of selected item.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. The right way is to requery databse after submit and search for the item text by item value.
2. You can cache **load_from_database** result values (in Session or HttpCache) and search item text from there.
3. Another approach is to append your model with another string field (like:
   public string selectedUserAppText { get; set; }
   pass it to your View:

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.selectedUserAppText)

Set its value with jQuery code like:

```
$("#your_dropdown_id").change(function(e) {
  var selectedText = $("#your_dropdown_id").children("option:selected").text();
  $('#your_hidden_for_id').val(selectedText);
});
```

after submitting this form your selectedUserAppText field will get selected item text.
Please check this in action at:
http://jsfiddle.net/m4zuH/1/

Comment: The value could be duplicated but the text doesn't. So I want to use the text as index. Any idea? All I want is the selected text or selected index from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

MVC must use the standard HTTP posting mechanism, and this mechanism does not contain the text of a dropdownlist.  It only contains the value.  Thus, you must.. on the server, lookup that value based on the id.

How you do that, depends on your app.  One option would be to call loadData() again, and then do a simple linq query to return the text.

```
var data = loadData();

var text = data.Where(x => x.Value == value).Single().Text;
```

Comment: The value could be duplicated but the text doesn't. So I want to use the text as index. Any idea?

Comment: @user838204 - so use the text as the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a custom selected value, then you need a little bit more of code in your dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedUserApp , new SelectList(Model.userApps, "Name", "Name"))
```

The SelectList is what you need because you can set which properties of your object will be the value or will be the text:

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);
```